# WiFi flush list of available networks (WIN10)

Tags: wireless-networking, router, windows-10

I have a laptop with win 10
I have received a new wireless modem (Zyxel WMG8924-B10A)

While having comp1 connected via wifi, I used comp2 to update settings on the router (update name and pw).

Now comp1 can only see the old name of the network on the list of available networks. And it can no longer connect to the network.

I have tried several things to update the list - including a system restore on the computer... what to do?

It seems that windows keeps a list of available wireless connections that cannot be resat (I'm guessing the name is stored with the mcac-address)

I have tried to:

- Delete the connection in control panel
- Remove it manually with cmd and regedit ([this guide](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/delete-wifi-network-profile-windows))
  netsh wlan delete profile name=”oldprofile“
  delete profile from: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
- Import new wifi profile from other computer
- Complete system restore

Comment: Delete the wireless connection on comp1 and create a new one ...

Comment: Tried that... manually (cmd) and under settings

Comment: Did you restart in between?

Comment: What did you do in the `cmd` shell?

Comment: In cmd: netsh wlan delete profile name=”oldprofile“

Comment: And if you do `netsh wlan show profiles` it is still there?

Comment: no... It is gone...

Comment: Try `netsh interface set interface name="<NIC name>" admin=disabled` then `netsh interface set interface name="<NIC name>" admin=enabled` then `netsh wlan show networks`